# How to override a method used by a 3rd party library

Tags: python

This would be the layout

some_function.py

```
def some_function():
    print("some_function")
```

some_library.py

```
from some_function import some_function

class A:
    def xxx(self):
        some_function()
```

main.py

```
from some_library import A
from some_function import some_function

def new_some_function():
    print("new_some_function")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_function = new_some_function
    a = A()
    a.xxx()
```

In the class `A`, the method `xxx`, calls `some_function`, so is it possible to override it with something else, without re-implementing the entire class?

Comment: Do you know about inheritance?

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned, I would have to write the whole method `xxx`, which would look clumsy and quiet big

Comment: This seems sort of hacky to me. Your minimal example is useful, but can you also provide the context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for *monkey patching* (means changing classes/modules dynamically while running). This way you don't need to overwrite the class `A` and use inheritance as suggested by other comments - you said you don't want that, so try this solution:

```
import some_class  # import like this or will not work (cos of namespaces)

def new_some_function():
   print("new_some_function")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Import and use like this, other ways of import will not work.
    # Because other way imports method to your namespace and then change it in your namespace,
    # but you need to change it in the original namespace
    some_class.some_function = new_some_function
```

That way replace the original method and even other classes will use it then. Be careful, if the original method is a class/instance method, you need to create new function with proper params, like this:

```
def new_some_function(self):
    # for instance methods, you may add other args, but 'self' is important

def new_some_function(cls):
    # for class methods, you may add other args, but 'cls' is important
```

Answer (score 2):

You provide very little information about your use case here. As one of the comments points out, this might be a case for inheritance. If you are in a testing context, you may not want to use inheritance though, but you might rather want to use a mock-object.

Here is the inheritance version:

```
from some_library import A

def new_some_function():
    print("new_some_function")

class B(A):
    def xxx(self):
        new_some_function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = B()
    a.xxx()
```

Note, how class `B` derives from class `A` through the `class B(A)` statement. This way, class `B` inherits all functionality from `A` and the definition of class `B` only consists of the parts where `B` differs from `A`. In your example, that is the fact that the `xxx` method should call `new_some_function` instead of `some_function`.

Here is the mock version:

```
from unittest import mock
from some_library import A

def new_some_function():
    print("new_some_function")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mock.patch('some_library.some_function') as mock_some_function:
        mock_some_function.side_effect = new_some_function
        a = A()
        a.xxx()
```

As mentioned above this approach is mostly useful if you are in a testing context and if `some_function` does something costly and/or unpredictable. In order to test code that involves a call to `some_function`, you may temporarily want to replace `some_function` by something else, that is cheap to call and behaves in a predictable way. In fact, for this scenario, replacing `some_function` by `new_some_function` might even be more than what is actually needed. Maybe, you just want an empty hull that can be called and that always returns the same value (instead of the `side_effect` line, you can specify a constant `.return_value` in the above code example). One of the key functionalities of mock objects is that you can later check if that function has been called. If testing is your use case, I would very much recommend looking at the documentation of the python mock module.

Note that the example uses the `mock.patch` context manager. This means that within the managed context (i.e. the block inside the `with`-statement) `some_library.some_function` is replaced by a mock object, but once you leave the managed context, the original functionality is put back in place.

Answer (score 0):

You may just create another class and override the method you need.
Just as an example:

```
class myInt(int):
    def __pow__(self, x):
        return 0

a = myInt(10)
a+10 # 20
a**2 # 0
```

In this case `a` is an int and has access to all the method of the `int` class, but will use the `__pow__` method I've defined.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is inheritance, You can subclass a class and with super method you can inherit all the parent class functions. If you want to override parent class functions, you just need to provide a different implementation by the same name in child class.
     from some_library import A
     from some_function import some_function

```
 def new_some_function():
     print("new_some_function")

class B(A):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(self)
       pass
    def xxx(self):
       new_some_function()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = B()
    a.xxx()

Output:
     new_some_function

you syntax may differ depending upon the python version.
In python3
class B(A):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__() 

In Python 2,
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
      super(ChildB, self).__init__()
```

Comment: Maybe because you just posted code with no explanation at all?